# PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

In my app I'm connected to a websocket.
The socket is sending JSON data. As it is becoming available I process it in a different Job. In each job, I convert the JSON to a model object with GSON. There are 3 types of models, all independent, and with one common timestamp field in a MappedSuperclass. They don't have an id explicit field. I call save on the model and in 1 out of 1000 times a "PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist" is thrown.

The multiple jobs are called from a start up Job that connects to the websocket. The library I'm using creates a different thread for each incoming message. I then convert the thread into a job before saving to the database. I do this, because otherwise another PersistentObjectException is thrown about changing the id from 1 to 2 or something similar, if I allow the original thread to call save.

I also have another job running that accesses the database at the same time. What could be wrong?

```
@Override
public void onMessage(final WebSocketMessage message){
        new Job() {
            @Override
            public void doJob() {
                processMessage(message.getText());
            }
        }.now();

}

 public void processMessage(String message) {
        Appointment appointment = new Gson().fromJson(message, Appointment.class);
        appointment.save();
 }

 @Entity
 public class Appointment extends CalendarEvent {
       private String owner;
 }

 @MappedSuperclass
 public abstract class CalendarEvent extends Model {
       private long timestamp;
 }
```

**EDIT:** Added some code sample

Comment: How do you identify the model objects? Is it possible that the value being placed in your @Id field is non-unique?

Comment: Each Model class has an id field, that is null. My classes extend Model. They don't declare an id field per se.

Comment: Btw, I don't really understand the meaning of this message. What does "detached entity passed to persist" mean in English? (I'm not a native speaker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this workaround to work for now. Maybe it's to do with how Gson and Jpa interact. Not sure...

```
public void processMessage(String message) {
        Appointment appointment = new Gson().fromJson(message, Appointment.class);
        //recreate appointment
        appointment = new Appointment(appointment);
        appointment.save();  }
```

Comment: Must be. How strange. I assume your `Appointment` copy-constructor always explicitly sets the `id` to `null` thus ensuring it is considered "new" to the EntityManager.

Answer (score 5):

Basically it means the `EntityManager` won't track them any more: [This is a good overview](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach). **How** they come to be considered detached when you didn't explicitly ask for it is odd. But the workaround *might* be to use a "defensive" approach in your DAO method and `merge` these odd cases; i.e.:

```
public void save (Model possiblyDetachedModel) {

   if (entityManager.contains(possiblyDetachedModel)) {
        entityManager.merge(possiblyDetachedModel);
    } else {
        entityManager.persist(possiblyDetachedModel);
    }
}
```

I don't particularly like it, because it shouldn't need to be done when you're `persist`ing brand-new objects. It might be worth putting some logging in (or debugging if at all possible) the "`merge`" branch and really inspecting those rogue objects - I'm pretty sure the `EntityManager` can only use the `@Id` field as the detection mechanism...

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've found a workaround that seems to work for now hopefully...